# C# Linq to xml. Items nested in parent object

Tags: c#, xml, linq, list, nested

I'm having a problem with a linq query and then serializing it into xml and I was hoping that someone can see where I'm going wrong. Linq is still a bit alien to me, so any help will be grateful.

Here's my linq query

```
var orders = (from o in db.orders
              where o.id == id
              select new Order
              {
                  OrderID = o.order_reference,
                  DeliveryAddress = new DeliveryAddress()
                  {
                      AddressLine1 = o.customer.address.address_1
                  },
                  OrderItem = (from oi in db.order_items
                               where oi.order_id == o.id
                               select new OrderItem()
                               {
                                   Item = oi.Item
                               }).ToList()
              }
              ).ToList();
```

And here's the xml output

```
<Order>
    <OrderID>W0003579579</OrderID>
    <DeliveryAddress>
        <AddressLine1>Address</AddressLine1>
    </DeliveryAddress>
    <OrderItem>
        <OrderItem>
            <Item>T-Shirt</Item>
        </OrderItem>
        <OrderItem>
            <Item>Jumper</Item>
        </OrderItem>
    </OrderItem>
</Order>
```

The problem is, I want OrderItem to not be a child of OrderItem like so

```
<Order>
    <OrderID>W0003579579</OrderID>
    <DeliveryAddress>
        <AddressLine1>Address Line 1</AddressLine1>
    </DeliveryAddress>
    <OrderItem>
        <Item>T-Shirt</Item>
    </OrderItem>
    <OrderItem>
        <Item>Jumper</Item>
    </OrderItem>
</Order>
```

This is my model

```
public class Order
{
    public string OrderID { get; set; }
    public DeliveryAddress DeliveryAddress { get; set; }
    public List<OrderItem> OrderItem { get; set; }
}

public class DeliveryAddress
{
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem
{ 
    public string Item { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my xml serializer

```
    private XDocument Serialize<T>(T source)
    {
        XDocument target = new XDocument();
        XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        System.Xml.XmlWriter writer = target.CreateWriter();
        s.Serialize(writer, source);
        writer.Close();
        return target;
    }
```

Comment: Simple.  You just need to add one line : [XmlElement("OrderLine")] then public List<OrderItem> OrderLine { get; set; }.  Declaring the object an XmlElement will eliminate the extra tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try annotating your class like this:

```
public class Order
{
    public string OrderID { get; set; }
    public DeliveryAddress DeliveryAddress { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("OrderItem")]
    public List<OrderItem> OrderLine { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That's perfect! It worked a dream, I was sure I tried that before, but clearly I hadn't.